# Which CPU option on the iMac Pro gives you two FMAs?

Tags: imac, imac-pro, processor, macos

I know for Skylake X you need a 61xx or better CPU to get two FMAs, but it’s not clear what the situation is with Skylake W ? Everything I have found for Skylake W just says “up to two FMAs”, without any specific detail as to which CPUs have 1 and which have 2?

Comment: dumb question but what is FMA?

Comment: Sorry - floating point multiply-accumulate - useful for heavy duty number crunching - cheaper Skylake CPUs have 1,  more expensive versions have 2.

Answer (score 1):

Only a [few low-end 4 core Skylake W CPUs are limited to one FMA](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/cores/skylake_w). Even the entry-level iMac Pro has an 8 core CPU, so it would appear that all iMac Pro configurations will have two FMAs.